# launching another activity what happens to arraylist in previous activity

Tags: java, android

I have an activity lets call it activity A which on creation downloads some data from a database. The data is stored in a custom ArrayList called myData.

When a user clicks on a button another activity called B is launched. Activity A passes some data to Activity B which I can do by making my class implement Parcelable.

My understanding when Activity B is lanuched that Activity A will be in either the onPause or onStop state. My question is will my arraylist myData still exist when Activity B is closed and the focus goes back to Activity A? If not how can I store this data?

Comment: If the Activity stays in onPause() - which is the case for "the user returns to the Activity", then there's no problem. But if it is in onStop() - which is the case for "the user navigates to the Activity", then the next method called will be onRestart(). And the ArrayList will be recreated new (and its previous values are then lost).

Comment: @ModularSynth if activity A goes into onStop state. Is there anyway of keeping my arrayList data? I.e. I do not want to recreate the arrayList onRestart?

Comment: If you don't kill and restart your Activity (you don't pass by the onCreate() method), then probably yes. But it would be safer to serialize the ArrayList to a file. Just in case. You know, these funny users... they like so much rotating their devices.

Comment: @mHelpMe you can add or use this to your AndroidManifest Activity [android:launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) using a `singleTop` what you've left in Activty A is the same when you finish the Activity B.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you launch a new activity, the previous activity goes in onStop state.

The definition of [onStop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle):

> Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because
>   another activity has been resumed and is covering this one. This may
>   happen either because a new activity is being started, an existing one
>   is being brought in front of this one, or this one is being destroyed.

See this chart

[image]

Now when you go back to ActivityA, the array data will still be present. So when switching of activities takes place this data is not destroyed and recreated once the activityA is again started.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can finish you `ActivityB` by using `finish()` method.  And your data of arrayList will exist when you will be back to `ActivityA`. And i will suggest to declare arrayList as  instance variable of `ActivityA` and fetch data on `onCreate()` method. so data will exist until activity destroy, so data will not fetch again when activity come to focus .